# Jquery/Javascript div selection via .each() gives HTMLDivElement object rather than Object object. What can be the workaround to hide the div object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, jquery

I have 5 `div` elements with attribute `data-role="content"`

I select all of them by

```
a = $('div[data-role=content]')
```

It returns `[object HTMLDivElement]`.

To hide all the `div` elements, I iterate through `a` and hide each element

```
<script>
$.each(a, function(index, value) {
    if (value) {
        alert(typeof(value));
        value.hide();
    }
})
</script>​
```

But it returns an error ....

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'a.hide' [undefined] is not a function
```

On the other hand, if I select a single div with the id:

```
a = $('div[id=content1]')
```

it gives me an:

```
 [object Object]
```

The hide function `a.hide()` works in that case.

The question is: "How can I select all the `[object Object]` elements at once?" or,
"How can I convert `[object HTMLDivElement]` to `[object Object]`?"

Comment: BTW, `alert()` converts its arguments to strings which can be less than useful, as you might have noticed here. This is a terrible way to debug. Instead of using `alert()` for debugging, use `console.log()` (and friends). To see the output, open your browser's console. IE8+, Safari, and Chrome have built-in consoles; for Firefox there's [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're ***really*** just looking for this:

```
var a = $('div[data-role=content]');
a.hide();
```

You don't need to explicitly iterate over every element in the jQuery object because [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) will take care of that for you.

---

***N.B.*** [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) is for iterating over any array-like object. When you're already working with a jQuery object, though, use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) instead of `$.each()`.

Also, it looks like you're using an attribute selector to select elements by ID. This is a silly way to select elements, as there's a much simpler — and potentially *much* faster — [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Here's the swap:

```
$('div[id=content1]') // Change this
$('div#content1')     // to this
```

You can do even better, though, because element IDs must be unique, which means that specifying an ID *and* an tag name is unnecessarily specific. So,

```
$('div#content1') // Change this
$('#content1')    // to this
```

---

Okay, so I couldn't resist following up on this whole ID selector bit to prove just how much faster a solo ID selector is.  In my tests: **an order of magnitude.** http://jsperf.com/jq-id-selectors

Comment: That is absolutely correct,never tried this one.. :) 
Thanks...
Still , is there any way to make the conversion [object HTMLDivObject]=>[object Object] ?

Answer (score 4):

The value passed to `each` is the actual DIV element itself, not a jQuery wrapped instance of the DIV. DIV elements don't have a hide method. You can use @Matt's suggestion which is the correct and shortest way since the `.hide()` call will be applied to all members of the `$(...)` result set. Or turn your value into a real jQuery selector with `$(value).hide()`.

Comment: That is also correct. 
And that explain the actual reason too...
Thank You!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for

```
a.each(function(index, item){

    $(this).hide;

});
```

That is the each that foreaches through a jquery object and actually makes "this" available.